# Join of reverse_nested aggregations in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Please help me to find a mechanism to aggregate over the following domain or to prove that it doesn't exist in the current API.

```
    curl -XDELETE 127.0.0.1:9200/test_index

    curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/test_index -d '{
        "mappings": {
            "contact": {
                "properties": {
                    "facebook_profile": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "education": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "year": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "google_profile": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "education": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "year": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }'

    curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/test_index/contact/contact1 -d '{
        "google_profile": {
            "education": "stanford", "year": 1990
        }
    }'

    curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/test_index/contact/contact2 -d '
    {
        "facebook_profile": {
            "education": "stanford", "year": 1990
        }
    }'
```

How one can query ES to find statistics about how many of contacts graduated from particular universities?

I found one possibility, but it doesn't give me desired result, since it can't answer on the question above with respect to contacts, but only to their particular profiles (nested docs):

```
    curl -XPOST '127.0.0.1:9200/test_index/_search?search_type=count&pretty=true' -d '{
        "aggs": {
            "facebook_educations": {
                "aggs": {
                    "field": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "contact.facebook_profile.education"
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "reverse": {
                                "reverse_nested": {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "nested": {
                    "path": "contact.facebook_profile"
                }
            },
            "google_educations": {
                "aggs": {
                    "field": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "contact.google_profile.education"
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "reverse": {
                                "reverse_nested": {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "nested": {
                    "path": "contact.google_profile"
                }
            }
        }
    }'
```

What gives me:

```
    "aggregations" : {
        "facebook_educations" : {
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "field" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ {
              "key" : "stanford",
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "reverse" : {
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            } ]
          }
        },
        "google_educations" : {
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "field" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ {
              "key" : "stanford",
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "reverse" : {
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            } ]
          }
        }
    }
```

But here I can't be sure if one found contact is the same or different doc(parent), respectively I can't answer to my initial question.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to [aggregate on multiple fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation). This is not directly supported in Elasticsearch, but there are ways to work around this and get the results you are looking for.

Have a look at the [discussion on Github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5100), and also in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation).

If I'm understanding correctly, whether "stanford" appears in `facebook_profile.education` or `google_profile.education`, you would like the `contact` to be counted only once in the aggregation.

You should be able to do this in one of two ways:

1. Use a script to concatenate the values stored in the fields:

   ```
   {
     "aggs": {
       "by_education": {
         "terms": {
           "script": "doc['contact.facebook_profile.education'].values + doc['contact.google_profile.education'].values"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. You can create create a new dedicated field at index time which contains the values from both fields, using the `copy_to` option. Then aggregate on the single field. For example, you could copy the contents of both fields to a new field called `education_combined`.

   ```
   {
     "mappings":{
       "contact":{
         "properties":{
           "facebook_profile":{
             "type":"nested",
             "properties":{
               "education":{
                 "type":"string",
                 "copy_to":"education_combined"
               },
               "year":{
                 "type":"integer"
               }
             }
           },
           "google_profile":{
             "type":"nested",
             "properties":{
               "education":{
                 "type":"string",
                 "copy_to":"education_combined"
               },
               "year":{
                 "type":"integer"
               }
             }
           },
           "education_combined":{
             "type":"string"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Then, simply aggregate on `education_combined`:

   ```
   {
     "aggs": {
       "by_education": {
         "terms": { "field": "education_combined" }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: your first suggestion simply doesn't work, because for nested docs you have to access _source field. Second option may work, but unfortunately not in my case, since I have nested docs wrapped into child docs and I'm trying to perform some sort of has_parent aggregation. This is what I've got for now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061945/match-query-inside-script-elasticsearch . Thank you anyway