# match_query inside script? [elasticsearch]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a quite complex aggregation, its complexity is caused by absence of has_parent aggregation.
Since so it's implemented using groovy. The only problem I have is to filter docs being counted in the aggregation.

Aggregation looks like this: https://gist.github.com/serj-p/c4fcc9810b3b627de294
the aim of this aggregation is to build the top of universities contacts are graduated from.
A contact doc has child docs, which are facebook profiles. 
Last ones have nested fields representing universities, that's why I access _source field.

As you probably can see, I perform filtering in the beginning :

```
                      {
                        "match_phrase_prefix": {
                          "organizations.name": "stan"
                        }
                      }
```

to exclude contacts not having relevant docs. "organizations.name" is analyzed as

```
           {
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "standard",
                    "trim",
                    "asciifolding",
                ],
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
```

the text being appleid to filter this field is being analyzed in the same way.
I found it very difficult to do the same processing of a field value and a filtering text inside of the script which should filter particular nested docs. That's why I am looking for some possibility to access ES API from the script to do so.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: When you start asking yourself how to do `match` inside a script to perform an aggregation, you know the things don't move in the right direction. **At this point, maybe it's time to re-think your data structure.** Data structure and queries work hand in hand. You don't model data then try to squeeze in queries. You do both, considering the queries you will run and the data requirements.

Comment: I have thought about changing data structure. However it is not the best possible solution for few reasons. They are: 
complexity of building mapping between original data and adopted to the ES; if I put these child docs into parent ones I'll lose advantages of P-CH and it becomes useless; if I split child docs in the way there will be only one field like education per child doc(no nested) it will significantly overload parent-child id mapping which is still very memory greedy, and won't solve my problem(there is no has_parent mapping). So I am looking exactly for what I asked